# Pass a variable to asset_path in my coffee.erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

In order to get the actual path of an image, I found this in the [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html):

`$('#logo').attr src: "<%= asset_path('logo.png') %>"`

I want to pass a variable `img_src` to `asset_path` instead of a fixed name like `logo.png`? I need to do this since I am dynamically figuring out the source of the image.

When I do:

`$('#logo').attr src: "<%= asset_path(img_src) %>"`

I get the following error : "undefined local variable or method `img_src`"

Comment: Is `img_src` a Ruby or CoffeeScript variable? Because inside the `<%= %>` tags, the ERB (Embedded Ruby) is expecting a Ruby variable, which is now not defined, hence the "undefined local variable or method" error.

Comment: yes, please show where and how img_src is defined